# SQL Server raiserror instruction does not raise exception in java code

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, exception, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, which does several updates/inserts. I call the execution of it using Hibernate from java client. I want this piece of code to raise an exception in java in case if procedure will raise an error (if one of the statements will fail because of constrain t violation for example). Quite straightforward, isn't it?

The java code looks like this:

```
getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {

        public Object doInHibernate(Session s) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            SQLQuery query = s.createSQLQuery("exec myProc :date");                             
            query.setTimestamp("date", new Timestamp(valDate.getTime()));
            try {
                query.executeUpdate();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {  ...  } }
```

in the procedure I'm inserting this statement to imitate error's happening.

```
raiserror('this is bad', 11, 1);
```

It works ok if this is the first statement of procedure, so if I call it from mgmt studio the output looks like this:

> Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Procedure upd_position_list_hist, Line 85
>   this is bad

Java code catches the exception, everything is ok.

But, if I place the error raising statement in the middle of the proc - after it does some updates/inserts - so that output will looks like :

> (0 row(s) affected) 
>   (1 row(s) affected)
>   (1 row(s) affected)
>   Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Procedure upd_position_list_hist, Line
>   85 this is bad

- this stops throwing an exception in java side. Code finished the executing, and no any HibernateException is thrown. What could be the issue and how can I solve it??

Comment: Are you sure that raises an exception, I seem to remember that lower values will raise a warning instead. Try with 18, or check `getWarnings()` on `Statement` and/or `Connection`.

Comment: Sounds like it is not reading to the end of the TDS stream to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried with 16, the same. And besides, it raises exception - as I wrote- if I place raiserror statement first in the proc. so I don't think it's related to low severity... How can I get warnings from the code I showed above? there is only hibernate session i can play with, no any Statement/Connection objects...

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, seems so to me as well. But the question is - how can I check it myself using Hibernate API? There are getMoreResultset method in Statement object, but I don't have it in Hib

Comment: @javagirl - No idea I don't use Java/Hibernate. If nothing else comes up maybe you could try `SET NOCOUNT ON` so that the error message still appears at the beginning of the stream not after the row count messages.

Comment: Please check this answer here [MSSQL JDBC Driver loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833543/3257274)

Answer (score 1):

`set nocount on` should fix this, because hibernate probably stops reading results after the first one, it doestn't expect multiple results from a single query.

But why would you use hibernate in the first place, for running a proc..