# Catch SQL RaiseError in jsp

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jsp

I am developing a database and some JSP Pages to perform CRUD operations on it.

I cannot catch exceptions related to my SQL Code in my JSP Code.

For Example:

I have this part of code where I raise an error in T-SQL:

```
IF @existing > 0
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR ('ID primário ja existe', 1, 1)
                        RETURN 0
                    END

                        IF (@CategoriaId IS NULL)
                            BEGIN
                                RAISERROR('O CategoriaId não pode ser nulo',1,1)
                                RETURN 0
                            END
```

I need to call the function where I raise those errors in JSP code.

Heres a part of the JSP Code:

```
try
            {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            }
            catch (Exception u)
            {

                out.println(u.toString());

            }
```

And it never returns the error from T-SQL.

However I know that the function reaches the catch statement because if I throw a println("test") in there it writes test on the jsp page.

I always get this exception : >com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

This is an insert operation I'm doing, and if I write the correct values it inserts without any problems. But even when it inserts it throws that exception.

Edit: I tried u.getMessage() already

Comment: Hi, have you checked that when you inserts correct values that these values are stored in the database ?

Comment: hey, yeah i checked that out. I went directly to the SQL Server and selected the entire table. The values are there. Thats why i find this so weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You really **should read** the exception message you get.*
The reason you don't get the exception from the database is probably because it's masked by the exception you get from the java.
I'm a .net guy myself, the last time I've worked with java was about 17 years ago, so I'm not familiar with the correct method you should use, but it's probably not `executeQuery`.
[According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281444/how-can-i-execute-non-query-stored-procedure-in-jdbc), you should use `execute` instead.

**Update**
After our conversation in the comments I've done some digging and found [this pearl in MSDN.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
Note this part:

> A RAISERROR severity of 11 to 19 executed in the TRY block of a TRY…CATCH construct causes control to transfer to the associated CATCH block. Specify a severity of 10 or lower to return messages using RAISERROR without invoking a CATCH block.

This means that your `raiserror`'s severity parameter should be somewhere within the range of 11 to 19.

Comment: well i tried that, it says:  Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to ResultSet. I Read and google the other exception and couldnt find anything, thats why i posted here :S

Comment: i googled this exception already and it returns a Boolean value. as a need a resultSet to be returned i can't use that statement.

Comment: If it's an insert statement, it doesn't produce a result set. therefor you need to change `rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);` to `Success = stmt.executeQuery(sql);` where Success is a boolean variable that will tell you if the insert was successful.

Comment: Does your stored procedure have a select statement as well as an insert statement inside?

Comment: it does have an Insert Statement. so in case i Insert a row succesfully it should find a result set right ? It doesnt have a select statement however. But shouldn't the RAISERROR keyword work like the Throw Exception in JAVA ??

Comment: i tried to change the variable as u said. Now it doesnt throw the exception of the resultSet. But it doesnt throw the RAISEERRORS either :S

Comment: If it doesn't have a select statement it can't create a result set. the `raiserror` statement should be transformed to a `SQLServerException` in java. try using `execute` without assigning to an rs: `stmt.execute(sql);` and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, in a previous comment I wrote `Success = stmt.executeQuery(sql);` where I should have write `Success = stmt.execute(sql);`

Comment: yeah i noticed, i tried the correct way :P created boolean variable Success and did Success = stmt.execute(sql). It works as i said in my previous comment. Didnt think about that SQLServerException, but it gives me an error : SQLServerException cannot be resolved to a type.
I guess SQLServerException isn't a reserved word or maybe im missing an Import

Comment: had to go for a moment, im back now. let me try :D

Comment: It worked ! thank you mate ! gotta do some digging on that Severity thing :)

Comment: Glad to help! a good place to start digging is the MSDN link in my answer. you can read some more about the raiserror statement in [this MSDN link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this with a Spring Boot project of mine. The Exception thrown would not contain the `RAISERROR` that exists in a MSSQL table's trigger. The `ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e)` would only get the message "The transaction ended in the trigger".

Up until now I had the MSSQL Driver loaded through my projects maven pom.xml file.
The moment I placed the MSSQL Driver in my JVMs jre/lib/ext folder the `RAISERROR` messages where included in the Java Exception.